# f is a differentiable function. Which of the limits is equal to f′(a)?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

[The options are shown in the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o19DM.png)

Answer is the last option. But i am not able to understand this at all.

I dont know how to approach this question. can someone explain this thoroughly. Thanks in advance.

FYI, I am total beginner

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last one applies. Let $c = 2h$. Then
$$\begin{align*}
 \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(a+2h)-f(a-2h)}{4h}
&= \lim_{c \to 0} \frac{f(a+c)-f(a-c)}{2c} \\
&= \lim_{c \to 0} \frac{f(a+c)-f(a) + f(a) - f(a-c)}{2c} \\
&= \lim_{c \to 0} \frac{f(a+c)-f(a)}{2c} +  \lim_{c \to 0} \frac{f(a)-f(a-c)}{2c}\\
&= \frac{2f'(a)}{2} = f'(a)
\end{align*}$$

Comment: what rule are you applying here? could you please explain that rule?

Comment: @SagarJoshi I applied the addition rule of limits on line $3$. Also, I'm allowed to replace $f(a) - f(a-c)$ by $f(a+c) - f(a)$ since $c \to 0$ and $f$ is continuous.

Comment: Hey I understood your answer. Could you please explain what did you try with other options? I mean how were you approaching other options? Thanks

Comment: @SagarJoshi Other options cannot be transformed into this form. I recognise the last option since the upper difference $2h - (-2h)$ is equal to the lower difference $4h$.

Answer (score 0):

I would say the last one sine you can apply L'hospitale rule to it. Another way is to use definition. Write: $\displaystyle \lim_{h\to 0} \dfrac{f(a+2h) - f(a-2h)}{4h} = \displaystyle \lim_{h\to 0} \dfrac{\dfrac{f(a+2h)-f(a)}{2h}+\dfrac{f(a)-f(a-2h)}{2h}}{2}= \dfrac{f'(a)+f'(a)}{2} = f'(a)$

Comment: could you please explain the definition?